# using cat6 to run 2 separate voltages 25 feet on the same cable?

Tags: dc

I have 2, 9VDC wall-warts and I want to use Cat6 to run this power 25 feet. Will it work and how much current loss can I expect?

Comment: Current loss... Right.

Answer (score 1):

CAT6 cable consists of 7 #32 AWG standard copper wires. According to [this page](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/AWG.phtml), #32 wire has a DC resistance of 0.54Ω per meter.

So a wire in a 25-ft-long CAT6 cable has a DC resistance of R<sub>W</sub> = 7.62m x 0.54Ω/m = 4.1Ω.

If the end-equipment draws 100mA then the voltage drop across the wire will be V<sub>W</sub> = 4.1Ω x 0.1A = 0.41VDC.

Although paralleling wires helps reducing the net wire resistance *(e.g. paralleling 3 of them makes 4.1/3=1.37Ω)*, the net wire resistance is still quite high. Also the heat dissipated by the wire at relatively high currents must be considered.

Comment: Thanks Rohat! I noticed you said that there 7 wires. Aren't there 4 pairs (which would be 8 wires)? I was hoping to use 2 pairs (4 wires) for each power supply. I believe one of the power supplies is rated 250 mA and the other is 1700mA, but I don't believe either will draw that much current. Thank you again!!!

Comment: What the power supply can deliver is of NO relevance, the current in the circuit is decided by the consumers (end-equipment)!

Comment: Where did you get the info that CAT6 cable uses AWG32 wires? Normal CAT6 cable uses AWG23 typically... https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-1000-ft-Blue-23-4-CAT6-CMR-Riser-Cable-56918949/202316391

Comment: @AliChen You're right, most CAT6 cables have #23 cables "typically". But there are #32s as well. I think I have come across the CAT6-32 cables (like [this](http://www.ugreen.com.cn/product-675-en.html) or [this](https://www.amazon.com/ACL-Ultra-Premium-32AWG-Ethernet/dp/B00ZJ8KLKW)) during research for the question.